# Как определить количество записей в группе

Tags: vkontakte-api

Хочу скачать все записи из открытой группы.
Использую wall.get, и скачиваю по 100 (макс.) увеличивая смещение пока запрос удаётся. Для скачивания работает хорошо, но чтобы проверить, добавилась ли ещё одна запись, приходится опять делать запросы на все записи - это долго и не эффективно.
Можно как-то попроще опросить количество записей одним запросом?

И можно ли получить список изменений в группе, произошедших за заданное время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял!
Нужно просто поставить offset на 0, count на 1 и убрать фильтр. В объекте response поле count показывает кол-во сообщений.

```
wall.get?domain=autism1&offset=0&count=1&extended=0&params[v]=5.50

response: {
   count: 2155,
```